# Muss man hier "den" oder "dem" schreiben?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Ich bin letztens auf einen Satz gestoßen, der meiner Meinung nach richtig war. Meine muttersprachliche Freundin meinte aber, dass er nicht ganz richtig ist.

Der Satz, Quelle unter dem [Link](https://www.ipb-halle.de/forschung/stress-und-entwicklungsbiologie/forschungsgruppen/induzierte-pathogenabwehr/):

> Zur Aufklärung von pflanzlichen Abwehrmechanismen gegen *Phytophthora infestans*, **den** Erreger der Kraut- und Knollenfäule der Kartoffel, wird die Interaktion von *P. infestans* mit der Wirtspflanze *Solanum tuberosum* und der Nichtwirtspflanze *Arabidopsis thaliana* untersucht.

Den Diskussionsstoff habe ich im Text **fett markiert**; sie meinte man kann hier sowohl *den* als auch *dem* benutzen könnte und das sie selber *dem* bevorzugen würde. Leider war sie nicht in der Lage, mir die unterliegende Grammatikregel zu erklären, da es eher eine Gefühlssache war.

Ich habe gelernt, dass der Artikel für männliche Substantiven mit *gegen* ein *den* sein sollte. Ändert der hinzugefügte Name zwischen Präposition und Artikel etwas? Welchen Artikel darf/soll man hier benutzen? Und vor allem warum?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die schon gegebene Antwort - *den* als einzige korrekte Form - ist zwar präskriptiv richtig. Es hat aber Gründe, warum Ihre Freundin hier auch *dem* akzeptabel findet.

Ergänzungen wie *den/dem Erreger der Kraut- und Knollenfäule* im Beispiel bezeichnet man als (lockere) Appositionen. Für diese gilt die Regel, dass grundsätzlich Kasusidentität zur Bezugsphrase herrscht. Dies ist besonders dann der Fall, wenn die Apposition (wie im Beispiel) ein Relativpronomen enthält. Deswegen ist in der Tat zu erwarten, dass es

> gegen [Phytophthora infestans]<sub>Akk.</sub>, **den**<sub>Akk.</sub> Erreger der Kraut- und Knollenfäule der Kartoffel

heißen sollte.

Es gibt in der Praxis allerdings verschiedene Tendenzen, von der Regel der Kasusidentität abzuweichen: Erstens gibt es die Tendenz, Appositionen in den Nominativ als eine Art "Nullkasus" zu setzen. Zweitens gibt es eine Tendenz, Appositionen in den Dativ zu setzen, wenn der Kasus der Bezugsphrase durch eine Präposition erzwungen ist. (*Zifonun et al.*, Grammatik der deutschen Sprache, Bd. 3, 1997, S. 2038). Man spricht hier auch von **Dativ-Appositionen**.

Beispiele:

- (1) Wegen des Doppelfeiertags, **dem** Reformationstag und Allerheiligen, verschiebt sich die Müllabfuhr zweimal. (Rhein-Zeitung, 17.10.2017, S. 15)
- (2) Solche Zwischenfälle sind in den Fußballarenen Argentiniens, **dem** Austragungsland der nächsten Fußballweltmeisterschaften, an der Tagesordnung. (Entnommen aus *Gippert*, op. cit.)

Warum Sprecher dies tun, ist fraglich. In einigen Fällen hat es wohl damit zu tun, dass die Bezugsphrase auch im Dativ stehen könnte (*Eisenberg*, Grundriss der deutschen Grammatik, Bd. 2, 4. Aufl. 2013, S. 465). Das könnte Beispiel (1) erklären (*wegen* wird von vielen Sprechern auch mit dem Dativ verwendet). Manchmal bestehen auch verbreitete alternative Konstruktionen, um die Bezugsphrase auszudrücken, die mit dem Dativ stehen; *Eisenberg* vermutet, dass auch dies zu einer Inkongruenz führen kann (so genannter **latenter Dativ**). Das könnte auf Beispiel (2) passen (*Argentiniens* könnte durch *von  Argentinien* ersetzt werden). Diese beiden Erklärungen scheinen auf Ihr Beispiel nicht zu passen. Jedoch ist schon nachgewiesen worden, dass Dativ-Appositionen auch in anderen Fällen auftreten (Gippert 1981).

Es bleibt also dabei: Standardsprachlich wird nur *gegen Phytophthora infestans, **den** Erreger der Kraut- und Knollenfäule der Kartoffel* akzeptiert. Die meisten werden ***dem***  hier als Fehler auffassen. Mit der Tendenz, die Apposition in den Dativ zu setzen, befindet sich Ihre Freundin dennoch in guter Gesellschaft.

---

Weiterführend:

- IDS/Grammis, [Systematische Grammatik: Appositionen](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1676)
- *Jost Gippert*, [Zur Dativ-Apposition im Deutschen](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/14506111.pdf), in: Beiträge zur Geschichte der deutschen Sprache und Literatur, 1981, Nr. 103, S. 31-62.
- *Fabio Mollica*, [latenter Dativ](https://www.degruyter.com/view/WSK/wsk_id_wsk_artikel_artikel_19146), in: *Schierholz/Uzonyi*, Wörterbücher zur Sprach- und Kommunikationswissenschaft (WSK) Online, 2018.

Comment: Klasse Antwort! Danke, das erklärt warum man intuitiv an "dem" denken kann.

Answer (score 12):

In diesem Fall ist einzig "den" korrekt, denn die Präposition "gegen" verlangt stets den Akkusativ und der Relativsatz "den Erreger der Kraut- und Knollenfäule der Kartoffel" bezieht sich auf "Phytophthora infestans", das Objekt der Präposition "gegen".

Comment: Danke für diese begründete Antwort. Das fasst auch meine Idee mithilfe der richtigen Konzepten zusammen. Wenn keiner Gegenargumente vorhält werde ich sie morgen akzeptieren :)