# Durch plus dative?

Tags: dative, accusative

> Nach dem Zweiten Weltkrieg wurde das Land in die Vereinten Nationen
> aufgenommen, und war zunächst eine konstitutionelle Monarchie, bis
> 1973 nach einem Staatstreich **durch Daoud Khan, dem ehemaligen
> Ministerpräsidenten**, die Republik Afghanistan ausgerufen wurde. Er
> herrschte wie ein Diktator und wurde wenige Jahre später wieder
> abgesetzt. Die Macht übernahmen nun Mitglieder der Khalq-Partei, die
> er zuvor bekämpft hatte.

Why is *durch* followed by *dem ehemaligen* instead of by *den ehemaligen*?

Source : https://www.kinderweltreise.de/kontinente/asien/afghanistan/daten-fakten/geschichte-politik/geschichte-politik-2/

Comment: It's wrong. *Den ehemaligen ...* would be correct.

Comment: See (in German): https://german.stackexchange.com/q/47319/35111

Answer (score 8):

This is simply a mistake.

The preposition [*durch*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/durch#Pr%C3%A4position) always demands accusative. Thus, the phrase should be

> durch … *den* ehemaligen Ministerpräsidenten

Answer (score 7):

This phenomenon is called "inkongruente Apposition" or in this case ["inkongruenter Dativ"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ#inkongruenter_Dativ).
It's an apposition that — as opposed to being in the same case as the component part it describes — is in the dative.

As others have already pointed out, it's not considered correct in standard German but it occurs frequently enough to have its own name and being [discussed scientifically](https://titus.uni-frankfurt.de/personal/jg/pdf/jg1981.pdf).