# Warum Dativ nach als?

Tags: preposition, dative, apposition

Zitat von einer gewöhnlich der deutschen Sprache mächtigen Quelle - dem [BVerfG](https://www.bundesverfassungsgericht.de/SharedDocs/Entscheidungen/DE/2006/02/rs20060215_1bvr035705.html#abs119):

> Das menschliche Leben ist die vitale Basis der Menschenwürde als tragendem Konstitutionsprinzip und oberstem Verfassungswert.

Wer kann begründen, weshalb nach "als" Dativ steht? Und worauf bezieht es sich? Bei Genitiv wäre es die Menschenwürde (und das wäre logisch, weil die Menschenwürde ein Konsitutionsprinzip ist), bei Nominativ Leben oder Basis ...

Comment: Dieser "inkongruente Dativ" wird seit vierzig Jahren diskutiert, siehe die [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/47321) zitierte Arbeit von Jost Gippert.

Answer (score 6):

Tja - welche Regel gilt? Der [Duden schreibt](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Funktionen-von-als) zur Kasuskongruenz bei der Apposition unter Verwendung von "als":

> Wenn jedoch das Bezugswort im Genitiv steht, dann gibt es zwei Möglichkeiten. Enthält die als-Gruppe ein Artikelwort, steht sie im Genitiv: *das Aufstellen des Christbaums als des wichtigsten Symbols für Weihnachten*. Enthält sie kein Artikelwort, wird sie in der Regel in den Nominativ gesetzt: *das Erscheinen des Sterns als leuchtender Wegweiser*.

Im Beispiel enthält die als-Gruppe kein Artikelwort, Teil 1 der Regel greift also nicht. Teil 2 der Regel gilt laut Duden nur "in der Regel". Verwendet man wie vorgeschlagen den Nominativ, könnte der [geneigte Leser](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/72816/392) annehmen, dass sich die als-Gruppe auf "vitale Basis" bezieht. Das geht nicht. Der Genitiv würde die Kongruenz und damit den Bezug deutlich machen, ist aber laut Duden nicht die Regel. Akkusativ geht gar nicht. Bleibt nur noch der Dativ? <sup>Schließlich gilt: "[Dativ geht immer](https://www.qiez.de/wochenende-berlin-trip-tipps/)!"</sup>

Ich hätte hier wahrscheinlich nach längerem Grübeln gegen den Duden entschieden und den Genitiv eingesetzt; dies geht wohl auch mit [anderen Stimmen konform, die von einer strengen Kongruenzregel ausgehen](https://www.contexta.de/kasuskongruenz/).

Comment: Ich finde den Dativ an der Stelle super eklig.

Comment: Spannend, als Schweizer klingt für mich der Dativ als richtig und natürlich und der Genitiv klingt machbar aber holprig.

Answer (score 4):

Ich befürchte, da ist dem Schreiber des Verfassungsgerichts ein - durchaus gängiger - Fehler unterlaufen - Ich kann keine Begründung für einen Dativ finden, beim besten Willen nicht - und @tohuwawohus Begründung, "wenn du nix besseres weißt, nimm Dativ" finde ich nicht sehr überzeugend.

Man könnte das "tragende Konstitutionsprinzip"

- als Adjunkt zu "Menschenwürde" betrachten, was logisch wäre (sie ist
  ein Konstitutionsprinzip"), was Genitiv erfordern würde, was aber eher ungewöhnlich (aber durchaus richtig, nur nicht gebräuchlich) wäre,
- als Adjunkt zu "Basis", was zwar grammatikalisch, schlecht aber
  semantisch zu begründen wäre - "eine Basis" ist kein
  Konstitutionsprinzip (außerdem würde das auf Nominativ herauslaufen) -
- als Adjunkt zu "Leben" (was auch ein Konstitutionsprinzip,
  zumindestens das Recht darauf, wäre) - das würde ebenfalls nach Nominativ rufen.

> ... als tragenden Konstitutionsprinzips ...

würde Kongruenz mit "Menschenwürde" herstellen, wäre als Genitiv vollkommen richtig, aber eher (zumindestensungebräuchlich.

> ... als tragendes Konstitutionsprinzip ...

würde Kongruenz mit dem Prädikativ insgesamt herstellen und damit den Nominativ verwenden.

Für den Dativ gibt es leider überhaupt keine Begründung (außer, dass es so oft falsch gemacht wird, dass es schon fast standardsprachlich geworden ist).

Ich empfehle die Lektüre [diesen](https://www.contexta.de/kasuskongruenz/) Artikels als vertiefendes Material, [Leo](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.xml?lang=de#id=3.3.2.3) kennt zumindestend das Problem mit dem falschen Dativ.